# Smooth shader not working | pdb addon loaded molecule

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

Maybe someone can help me with this. I am in Blender 2.80 and I used the pdb loader add-on. Now I have some problems with getting a smooth shader on the bonds of my molecule. That was never an issue in 2.79 (and older). Does anyone know how I could solve that? Any help or input on how to solve that would be greatly appreciated!

Verena

[image]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you enabled the *Smooth* option for the *sticks / bonds* in the import settings?

Comment: Yes I have, but there no difference in the outcome... However, I might have figured out how to deal with it. Increasing the number in the "sector" section (in the import settings) to something like 500 works perfectly fine. Maybe not the most elegant way, but it serves the purpose :)